# How to change """fasdfe""" into "fasdfe" in csv files using awk?

Tags: linux, awk

My file.csv has 2 columns and looks like this right now:

```
"""lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA""",7.767066345448011e-05
"""ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA""",5.406898520316803e-05
"""FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw""",8.7088198609513e-05
...
```

Is there any way to convert it to:

```
"lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA",7.767066345448011e-05
"ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA",5.406898520316803e-05
"FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw",8.7088198609513e-05
...
```

using awk in ubuntu?

Updated question: how to change

```
"lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA",7.767066345448011e-05
"ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA",5.406898520316803e-05
"FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw",8.7088198609513e-05
...
```

to

```
lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA,7.767066345448011e-05
ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA,5.406898520316803e-05
FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw,8.7088198609513e-05
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk -v FS='"""' '{print "\""$2"\""$3}' file
"lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA",7.767066345448011e-05
"ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA",5.406898520316803e-05
"FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw",8.7088198609513e-05
```

You could simply do this through sed,

```
$ sed 's/"\+/"/g' file
"lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA",7.767066345448011e-05
"ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA",5.406898520316803e-05
"FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw",8.7088198609513e-05
```

**Answer for the Updated question:**

```
$ awk -v FS='"' '{print $2$3}' file
lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA,7.767066345448011e-05
ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA,5.406898520316803e-05
FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw,8.7088198609513e-05
```

OR

```
$ awk '{gsub(/"/,"")}1' file
lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA,7.767066345448011e-05
ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA,5.406898520316803e-05
FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw,8.7088198609513e-05
```

Try the below awk code if you want do the above steps in a single command.(ie, removing all the `"""`)

```
$ cat file
"""lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA""",7.767066345448011e-05
"""ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA""",5.406898520316803e-05
"""FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw""",8.7088198609513e-05
```

---

```
$ awk '{gsub(/"""/,"")}1' file
lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA,7.767066345448011e-05
ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA,5.406898520316803e-05
FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw,8.7088198609513e-05
```

Comment: Thx for the fast reply and could you help me with the new updated question?

Comment: @user3692521 added. Any further questions?

Comment: Thank you so much do you know how to use awk to convert lines like /cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd,-112.263 to "/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd",-112.263? add the double quote?

Comment: From lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA,7.767066345448011e-05 to "lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA",7.767066345448011e-05

Comment: try this `awk -F, '{print "\""$1"\""FS$2}' file`

Comment: What if to convert the first two columns? /cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd,dfadsfadsfasdf,-112.263 to "/cw-0yLGNekxk4Vup/cwdd","dfadsfadsfasdf",-112.263

Comment: try `awk -F, '{print "\""$1"\""FS"\""$2"\""FS$3}'` . I think there wouldn't be more

Comment: @user3692521 This is not what the site is designed for. Rather than asking for many variations on the original question, you should try to understand what the code is doing and work out how to change it yourself. If you don't understand how the original code works (it seems like you don't), you should ask for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ cat f.csv
"""lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA""",7.767066345448011e-05
"""ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA""",5.406898520316803e-05
"""FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw""",8.7088198609513e-05

$ awk '{gsub(/\042+/,"\042",$1); print}' f.csv
"lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA",7.767066345448011e-05
"ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA",5.406898520316803e-05
"FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw",8.7088198609513e-05

$ awk '{gsub(/\042+/,"",$1); print}' f.csv
lkBBW4/9BbP/xKxPodjUPA,7.767066345448011e-05
ogiEVE6t+YVtvR1y/56nKA,5.406898520316803e-05
FxfYC7JayTJ+pYdr2qhHsw,8.7088198609513e-05
```

You have to use the octal codes for quotes to make sure everything is escaped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to use awk, this looks to me like a simple substitution which can be done using sed:

```
sed 's/"""/"/g' file
```

Or for the second one `sed 's/"//g' file`.